# Python save to new line in csv

Tags: python, csv, ip

I try create a scipt that running through some ip adresses, and ping these.
I have a problem, that when i save to csv, it writes all the ip, and have the status 1 in one long line

I will like to have these in separate lines. I can't figure out how to do this

Anyone that can help me?

```
hostnames = 
['10.245.0.100','10.245.0.800','google.com','10.45.80.21','10.33.33.21'] 
#example

#mylist = 0
#liste = 0

#for i in hostname:
#    value = os.system("ping -c 1" + i)
#    print("ip er ", i)
#    print(value)
#    if value == "1":
#        print("skrammel")
# 
#print("værdien er", i)



import os
import csv

liste2 = []

for hostname in hostnames:
    response = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + hostname)
if response == 0:
    print (hostname, 'is up')
elif response == 1:
    print (hostname, 'is down')
    with open('bruger.csv', 'a', newline ="\n") as fd:
        fd.write(hostname+",")


print ("Første kørsel gennemført")

with open('bruger.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
    response2 = os.system('ping -c 1 ' + hostname)
    if response == 0:
        print(hostname, 'is up')
    elif response == 1:
        print(hostname, 'is down')
    print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
```

Comment: your indentation seems wrong, could you give it a once over? also it appears you are not actually printing a newline to the file at any point, so of course its all one line

Comment: more specifically, if you just want one address per line just change `fd.write(hostname+",")` to `fd.write(hostname+"\n")`

Comment: Why aren't you using `csv.writer`? Why is newline `'\n'` instead of `''`?